# simpel php upload, how i can make an auto increment name and set allow type and improve security in applicaiton level

Tags: php, mysql

this is the form to upload the file and insert the values to mysql,
**the database:**

```
id -------- auto increment
name-------
filename---
```

**file structure:**

```
/database.php----------the pdo database connection
/upload.php------------this will be the forme
/upload_class.php------this will be the class to upload
/filefolder------------this is the folder where file will be upload
```

the connection function(**database.php**):

```
class Database {
    protected $host='localhost';
    protected $user='root';
    protected $db = 'dms';
    protected $pass = '';
    protected $conn;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dms","root","");
        $this->conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    }
}
```

after connection i will make a form (**upload.php**) to insert and send the values to insert fucntion:

```
<?php
     require_once('./upload_class.php');
    if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
        $uploadclass-> name= $_POST['name'];
        $uploadclass-> filename= $_FILES['filename']['name'];
        $uploadclass-> insert();
    }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table border="0" class="form_au">
            <tr><td>nameه</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="input1" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>filetoupload</td>
                <td><input name="filename" type="file"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="insert" class="button" value="upload"/></td></tr>
       </table>
    </form>
```

now here this is the upload class (**upload_class.php**) which will check and upload file to folder named (file_folder) and insert the values to database if the file gets upload success fuly.

```
<?php
    include ('detabase.php');
    class Uploadclass extends database{
        public function insert() {
                $targetFLE = "./filesfolder";
                $targetFLE = $targetFLE . basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO dab_din (name,filename,) VALUES (:name,:filename)";
                $result = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $targetFLE)) { 
                    $query = $result -> execute(array(":name"   =>$this -> name,
                                                        ":filename"     => $_FILES['filename']['name']));
                    if($query){echo $message = "success and file uploaded";} else {echo "failed on insert to dabas";}
                 } else { $message = "please select file";}

            }
        }
        $uploadclass = new Uploadclass();


    ?>
```

NOTE: i have not set the security and validation so i could be quik on my question but i have in real, so the question is only on uploading part

**My questions:**

1- file upload, name should be change like(file_1, file_2, file_3) and then upload to the folder,  for the solution i found to create a new select base on previous name been added to database but it will make the application work slow. and duplication chances as there will be many uses uploading in same time so if tow in one exact time will give the result of same value for there select. so how i can change name auto increment not the random name.

2- how i can set type and make it more secure only on the uploading part and only allow pdf

3- in application side what are the most important security step for php, else of type assigning.

regards

Comment: Only allowing PDF is possible with the `$_FILES`-Array. If you `print_r` it, you can see it has a index called `mime-type` which makes it possible to check for a PDF type.

Comment: @YUNOWORK yes i set but how i can keep the nameing means first file should be like(file_1) then (file_) .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 1:

The easiest solution will be to select the highest ID from the Database with `MAX`:

```
$id = $db->GetOne("SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM database");

$filename = $_FILES['filename']['name'] . "_" . $id;
```

Another solution would be to save the highest value seperatly somewhere and increment it everytime a pdf is uploaded. In that way, you dont have to look through the whole table.

Comment: the application will be used my many people at one time, so what if tow user send the ($id) query at same time so the file name for user one will be like (filename_10) and for user tow will be (filename_10) as they have run the query at exact same time, so duplication and error if i keep the column unique and that is bug of application....